# What would this print under call-by-name and call-by-value?

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, sml, callbyname, call-by-value

I have this line of code in a toy-language. The `print`-function takes a list of arguments and prints those.

`print(a, (a := 5, a))`

Would there be a difference in the output if I used call-by-value or call-by-name? If so, what would the outputs be.

It can be asumed that `a` is initialized to `0`.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of `print`

Comment: What is your stance at it? What material on evaluation strategies have you read, what is still unclear?

Comment: I am writing a compiler for a project, and someone told me that in call-by-name it would print `0 5` whereas with call-by-value it would print `5 5`. His argument was, that under call-by-value it would first evaluate all the expressions, and afterwards print the results. Is there any truth to this?

Comment: If at all, he seems to have gotten it reverse. A call-by-value with strict evaluation and left-to-right evaluation of arguments would pass `0` and `5`.

Comment: I thought "call-by-name" meant passing arguments by reference, but it actually means lazy evaluation of arguments, where the argument is evaluated once for each 'usage' in the function body. What useless terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With "call-by-value" arguments are *usually* evaluated left-to-right (in most languages), so the expression would be equivalent to something like this:

```
arg1 := a // copy value of a to arg1
a := 5 // copy 5 to a
arg2 := a // copy value of a to arg2
print(arg1, arg2) // print(0, 5)
```

"call-by-name" is apparently a form of lazy evaluation which would yield something like this:

```
arg1 := function() {return a;}
arg2 := function() {a := 5; return a;}
print(arg1, arg2)
```

So in this case the result will depend on two things:

- whether, in this language, closures capture variables by reference or by value. If capture by value, the `a := 5` won't affect the value of `a` that the first closure has captured. However, most languages which allow reassigning of local variables implement capture-by-reference (e.g. JavaScript).
- The order in which the `print` function decides to evaluate its arguments - depends how it's written.

If the closures capture by value, the `print(…)` will yield `0 5`, because the assignment `a := 5` only affects the second closure's copy of `a`.

If closures capture by reference then I can only guess at what the output might be. But it's quite likely the `print` function will do something like this:

```
print := function(lazy x, lazy y) {
    writeToOutput(x())
    writeToOutput(y())
}
```

In which case the result will be the same (`0 5`), because `x()` is evaluated first, the result processed, then `y()` is evaluated. In this case the value of `a` doesn't change until after the function is done with `x`.

But this is only a guess; `print` could evaluate them in any order (and any number of times).

Comment: "arguments are usually evaluated left-to-right (in most languages)" Notable counter examples are C, C++ and OCaml. In those languages evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified (and often implemented as right-to-left).

Comment: @sepp2k: also scheme and friends